# reference objects without materials

Tags: scripting, materials, blend-files

We are making our thesis film on maya for the rigging options, and prefer blender for the render, amongst other things because we want multilighting with ramp shaders. Our problem is that we want to animate parts of the background witout having to reassign shaders for each file.

So we came up with a solution. Import the animation in alembic from maya into blender, save the file, open a new file and then link the objects from the previous file, then add overrides and create materials.
The idea would be to swap alembic files in the original file; and in the new file, have an updated version with the shader overrides.

The problem is that when we try that, the file does update, but the new shaders are gone.

I found this video that looks a bit like what we'd want, but it's for visibility, not materials. https://theduckcow.com/2018/blender-overrides/

Thanks in advance ! 
[image]
EDIT: here's a simplified version of what we achieved in blender, and that would be less easily achievable in maya.

Comment: I don't think, this is possible. Are the vertex indices of the alembic accessible and always the same after each new export/import? (I don't really understand why you wouldn't use a render engine of your native engine; it will surely make your workflow easier.)

Comment: I don't understand the beginning, sorry. For the rest, I would prefer blender to save compositing time, in terms of workflow. On blender I have my render layers that I can composite and see changes near real time using eevee, I can adjust shadow bugs and the like, which allows me to spend more time on the render. I tried using maya software and Nuke/Natron but it was less intuitive... The problem is mainly that we want a toon render. But if there's no solution, I'll use maya, no biggie. I'm just sad there's not more transversality...

Comment: I understand now (For a simple toon shader maya hardware may be enough). Perhaps you could upload a simplified example alembic and link it from the post and an image of what the shaders should look like in Blender.

Comment: Hmm, didn't understand the alembic part, which file/parts do you want exactly ? I joined an image of the final result and one of the shaders (the primary shader for the wall)

Comment: The general idea of using linking and overrides seems correct, but they are still a work in progress. Perhaps some specific step you're making doesn't work yet.

Comment: Ok, thank you ! thought I had answered. 
We'll make it in blender, because maya's not good for what we want. we'll probably have to come up with a script then. Doesn't seem too hard, since there's history commands like in maya, it'll probably save us time. We'll share if we run into something interesting. And if anyone else has ideas, please share !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKAY ! So finally, after playing around with various scripts found on this website, assembling them, we found out  we had taken it the wrong way, as blender workflow is different from maya. The material is applied after in maya, and before in blender. 
The solution is a simple script that asks objects from the scene to be applied a premade material. In maya, naming is important for referencing, so our objects always have the same name. It's a bit fastidious to enter each name individually the first time, but it works out for us, as we simply run the script for each panel thereafter.

Here's our frankenbaby: (replace lama with whatever name you have)

```
import bpy
ob = bpy.data.objects.get("lama")

# Get material
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Lamamat")
if mat is None:
    # create material
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Lamamat")

# Assign it to object
if ob.data.materials:
    # assign to 1st material slot
    ob.data.materials[0] = mat
else:
    # no slots
    ob.data.materials.append(mat)
```